# Apple Mach-O linker Error Xcode 6.2

Tags: ios, xcode, mach-o

I'm sorry if this question is a duplicate, but I only asked it because I didn't find a solution in other related questions.

I started a new project in Xcode 6.2 and I imported `AFNetworking` using pods. I also imported `SWRevealViewController` by dragging the two files (.h and .m) into the project.

Everything looks fine but when I build the project to test it gives me the error below.

[image: Error Screenshot]

Does anyone know how to deal with this?

Comment: Have you deleted the derived data and cleaned the project? Do the imported files require any frameworks adding? ie Quartz

Comment: Show us ArticlesViewController and MainViewController.

Comment: Yes i cleaned the project, when i clean the project the error goes away, but when i build again it re-appears again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the same symbols `jsonContents`, `dictionary`, etc in 2 object files (`ArticlesViewController.o` and `MainViewController.o`).

This often happens when you import a header file that defines the symbols, for example:

SomeHeader.h

```
NSMutableArray *jsonContents;
NSMutableDictionary *dictionary;
```

Rather than declaring them as `extern`:

SomeHeader.h

```
extern NSMutableArray *jsonContents;
extern NSMutableDictionary *dictionary;
```

and define those variables in their own implementation file (`SomeFile.m` for example).

Comment: Thanks man! i didn't notice that duplication, but just curious, those are two different classes, why is that an error ?

Comment: @ANA When you import that header file those variables become part of each object file.  As they are global the linker complains with the *duplicate symbol* error as it doesn't know which of those variables to use when they are referenced elsewhere.